# How to fix Named Query Error ( unexpected token: DAY ) in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, named-query

Following is my named query for finding activities older then 90 Days:

```
"DELETE FROM PAActivity pa WHERE pa.status IN (:statusSet) AND cast(pa.datoFinish as date) < cast(DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL (:noofdays) DAY) as date)"
```

During compile time it gives following Hibernate exception:

```
ERROR 2018-04-24 11:00:07,579 o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter - line 1:243: unexpected token: DAY
ERROR 2018-04-24 11:00:07,579 o.h.h.i.a.ErrorCounter - line 1:243: unexpected token: DAY
line 1:243: unexpected token: DAY
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.primaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.atom(HqlBaseParser.java:3472)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlBaseParser.unaryExpression(HqlBaseParser.java:3250) .
.
.
.
.
WARN  2018-04-24 11:00:07,641 o.h.h.i.a.HqlParser - HHH000203: processEqualityExpression() : No expression to process!
ERROR 2018-04-24 11:00:08,094 o.h.i.SessionFactoryImpl - HHH000177: Error in named query: deletePAActivityByProcessIDs
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: DAY near line 1, column 243 [DELETE FROM fn.gover.model.PAActivity pa WHERE pa.status IN (:statusSet) AND cast(pa.datoFinish as date) < cast(DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL (:noofdays) DAY) as date)]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
```

Comment: This might just be helpful here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10223929/7953365

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that HQL doesn't support INTERVAL

You can solve you problem in 2 ways.
First - RestrictionCriteria

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -90); 
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Yourclass.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.ge("datoFinish", c.getTime());
List results = criteria.list();
```

Or just change your query like :

```
AND cast(pa.datoFinish as date) < cast(:dateMinus90 as date)
```

And set parameter as result of Calendar

```
.setParameter("dateMinus90", c.getTime())
```

The seccond way is to inherit dialect class and register sql function. For example for Oracle.

```
public class MyOracleDialect extends Oracle10gDialect {
    @Override
    protected void registerFunctions() {
        super.registerFunctions();
        registerFunction("sub_days", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.DATE, " date_sub(?1, INTERVAL ?2 DAY)"));
    } }
```

And then in hibernate props you should use this dialect. But I think it is not the best way.